# Need help. Getting error while restoring NuGet Packages

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore, build-pipeline

I have a Azure DevOps Pipeline which is trying to Restore NuGet Packages to one of my Project. It is failing with below error. I'm unable to resolve it and move further.

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://cesis.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Internal/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Comment: Is your feed is in the same project as the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
I had to create new PAT Token and apply the token to Pipeline and things started working.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)